# Sprite jump to center of sprite on touching it

Tags: android, andengine, sprite

i am trying to study andengine. When i am touching on center of sprite(tree) everything works fine. But when i am touching on top of the sprite it jump to the center of the sprite.

hope my question is clear.

[image: image 1 touch on center marked as red circle]

[image: image 2 touched on top of the tree but it jumped to where i jumped.]

this is the on touch event code i am using

```
final Sprite face = new Sprite(centerX, centerY, this.mFaceTextureRegion,   this.getVertexBufferObjectManager()) {
        @Override
        public boolean onAreaTouched(final TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent, final float pTouchAreaLocalX, final float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
            this.setPosition(pSceneTouchEvent.getX() - this.getWidth() / 2, pSceneTouchEvent.getY() - this.getHeight() / 2);
            return true;
        }
    };
```

Comment: this.setPosition((pSceneTouchEvent.getX() - this.getWidth()) / 2, (pSceneTouchEvent.getY() - this.getHeight()) / 2);

Comment: Actually, I didn't see a question here. Are you asking how to move the sprite, wherever you grab it without it centering on the touch point?

Comment: The question is unclear. Do you want the image to jump where you press or not? If not, then you should remove the line pointed out by @MoshErsan, because that is setting the position of the sprite centered around your touch point.

Comment: oh am sorry, my actual problem is, even if touch on the top of the tree the touch jump to center of it. where ever i touch(on tree) it jumps to center of the tree.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want  your sprite to center of the Scene when you touch it on any part of sprite,
But you are using onAreaTouched for that use should use IOnSceneTouchListener for that like below :-

```
@Override
    public boolean onSceneTouchEvent(final Scene pScene,
            final TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent) {
          this.setPosition(pSceneTouchEvent.getX() - face.getWidth() / 2, pSceneTouchEvent.getY() - face.getHeight() / 2);

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your time.. but thats not what i wanted.. i cannot touch the top of tree. ie if i touch on top of it the touch jumps to center of the tree.